# Lua.efi package for running lua in EFI environment

Tags: lua, uefi

Can someone please provide a link to download lua.efi package for running lua in EFI environment.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any pre-built Lua binaries for UEFI, but the [code is available in EDK2](https://github.com/tianocore/edk2/tree/master/AppPkg/Applications/Lua), so you can build it yourself.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/tianocore/edk2.git
$ cd edk2
$ . edksetup.sh
```

Then edit AppPkg/AppPkg.dsc, deleting the leading `#` from the line

```
#  AppPkg/Applications/Lua/Lua.inf
```

Then build `Lua.efi` with

```
$ build -a <ARCH> -t GCC5 -p AppPkg/AppPkg.dsc -m AppPkg/Applications/Lua/Lua.inf
```

Where `<ARCH>` is your intended target architecture. Likely one of IA32, X64, or AARCH64.

If building with GCC 6 (using GCC5 build profile), you may need to apply [this patch](https://lists.01.org/pipermail/edk2-devel/2017-April/010285.html) in order to avoid build failures.

The generated binary will be found in `Build/AppPkg/DEBUG_GCC5/<ARCH>/`.